# cannot cast expression of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement to type XXX

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting compiler error: cannot cast expression of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement to type AutomationStatusType
What am i doing wrong?

xml:

```
<Status>
    <Version>33</Version>
    <Status>Running</Status>
</Status>
```

query:

```
var query = (from status in doc.Descendants("Status")
    select new AutomationStatus
            {
                Version = (string)status.Element("Version"),
                Status = (AutomationStatusType)status.Element("Status"),
            });
```

classes:

```
public class AutomationStatus
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public AutomationStatusType Status { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public enum AutomationStatusType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Idle,
    [EnumMember]
    Running
}
```

**Edit:**
after reading your comments, i indeed added the following casing:

```
Status = Enum.Parse(typeof(AutomationStatusType), (string)status.Element("Status")),
```

Now i am getting a compilation error:
Cannot convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'Verint.AP2.Manager.AutomationStatusType'

However, if i create an anonymous class i am being able to get rid of the errors:

```
    var query = (from status in doc.Descendants("AutomationStatus")
                 select new /*AutomationStatus*/
                            {
                                Version = (string)status.Element("Version"),
                                Status = Enum.Parse(typeof(AutomationStatusType), (string)status.Element("Status")),
                                TimeStamp = (DateTime) status.Element("TimeStamp")
                            });
```

What can be the issue, how can i create the class (non anonymous?)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following snippet when you parse the status instead of the Row you have now.

```
Status = Enum.Parse(typeof(AutomationStatusType), status.Element("Status")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no [type conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx) between [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340098.aspx) and your enum. You need to [convert the XElement to a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx) and [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) the string to the enum:

```
{
    Version = (string)status.Element("Version"),
    Status = (AutomationStatusType)Enum.Parse(
        typeof(AutomationStatusType), (string)status.Element("Status")),
}
```

Comment: When i try to parse it as you said, I am getting error: Cannot convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'Verint.AP2.Manager.AutomationStatusType'

Answer (score 0):

though your code is not showing it im guessing that you are loading an XmlDoc or something.

use `XmlSerializer` instead.

something along the lines of:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutomationStatus));
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
 AutomationStatus x;
 x = (AutomationStatus) serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: why do you think it would be best to use XmlSerializer over linq?

Comment: I would say it is simpler in terms of coding - not necesarrily better.    And dependant of how it is used XmlSerializer may be faster.  Perhaps I should have said "you could use XmlSerializer instead"